# Any other way to specify listView Activity on Each index other then position?

Tags: java, android-activity, position

i want to start listView activity on each index of listView  done this with POSITION but this caused error while searching (open different activity) so i want to use any other different method for this mean to specify activity o list view

My code is here :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityOne.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }else if (position == 1)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }else if (position == 2)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityThree.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
```

.
.
.
and so on

Comment: What do you mean by `this caused error while searching (open different activity)`? What error did you get?

Comment: like on index one it put ActivityOne and on two ActivityTwo and so on but while searching (now search something like funny )e.g  it shows five results.On clicking first result of SEARCH it opens ActivityOne (following index but not activity fof its own)??

Comment: You should show how are you populating listview.

Comment: okay problem solved fanks for answer